# take id from select query in pg promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, pg-promise

when i log data.id the result is undefined 
when i log data the result is

[ anonymous {

id: 23,
   username: 'vvv',
   password: '1',
   description: null,
   cutprice: null,
   salname: null,
   image: null,
   counter: 0 } 
]

```
app.post('/api/hairdresser/signin', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body)
  connection.connect();
 var name = req.body.name;
 var password = req.body.password
  db.any('SELECT * FROM hairdressers where username = $1 ', 
 name).then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    console.log(data.id);
   }).catch(function(error) {

console.log(error);

 });
})
```

Comment: Try data[0].id, I think data is an array

Comment: Glad to help, make sure you accept Vitaly's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [any](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#any) is documented to resolve with an array of rows, so `data[0].id` is the value you are looking for.

Most likely what you need in this scenario though, is method [oneOrNone](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#oneOrNone), which resolves with the row-object, or `null` when none returned:

```
db.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM hairdressers where username = $1', name)
  .then(data => {
     // data = row object, or null when user not found;
     console.log(data && data.id);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      // more than 1 user found, or a different error
  });
```